# Permutations alphabetically ordered

Tags: c, permutation

I am struggling with my assignment. Our task is to make all possible permutations from the input (alphabetically ordered already). My code works only for 3 characters, after that it is not doing, what I expect it to do. I have been looking for a mistake for 5 hours now, without any success.

```
void perm(char *input_arr, int len_arr, int done) {
    if (done == len_arr - 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len_arr; i++) {
            printf("%c", perm[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        for (int i = done; i < len_arr; i++) {
            swapityy_swap(&perm[done], &perm[i]);
            sperm(perm, len_arr, done + 1);
            swapityy_swap(&perm[done], &perm[i]);
        }
        qsort(perm, len_arr, sizeof(char), compity_dawg);
    }
}
```

Looking forward to hearing from you, luv <3

Comment: It seems unlikely that the code you've presented works *at all*, at least if you define "works" as printing permutations of the array that `perm()` receives via parameter `input_arr`.  It would have to actually examine the contents of the array to achieve that.  And before that, it would have to actually compile.

Comment: when asking about a runtime error, as this question is doing, it is required to post code that cleanly compiles, is short, and still shows the error.  Post the input data,  Post the actual output, Post the expected output.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks ( for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.  (consider a closing brace '}. to be a separate statement.

Comment: the posted code is missing the #include statements, the input data, the expected output, the actual output, the main() function, the comity_dawg() function. the swapityy_swapp() function. The posted function is named: perm() and it has 3 parameters, but those recursive calls only have a single parameter

Comment: I would add to what @user3629249 said above: A library function  `qsort` sorts arrays – but you pass a **function** to it (the first param is `perm`)! The same problem with `swapityy_swap` calls... Also, you make something like a recursive call – but the callee is actually **not** the caller (`sperm` vs. `perm`)! In general: this is **not** a running or even compilable code. It does not _work_ al all.

Answer (score 1):

Given an array of characters, say `"acute"`, you can make a next permutation in alphabetical order this way:

- identify a reverse-sorted suffix ('tail') of the word; in this example it's `"ute"`;
- if the suffix is the whole word, you have the last permutation – stop; otherwise take the character preceding the suffix; in this example it's `'c'`;
- find in the suffix a smallest character greater than the preceding one; in the example the smallest character among `"ute"` which is greater than `'c'` is `'e'`;
- swap them; you get the suffix `"utc"` preceded by `'e'`;
- reverse characters in the suffix (sort them alphabetically) and you have the next permutation: `"aectu"`.

If you start iterating the above algorithm on a string of characters given in alphabetic order (e.g. `"acetu"`), you'll get all permutations in alphabetic order and stop with the string in reverse-alphabetic order (`"uteca"`).

EDIT1

Thanks to the *'a smallest character greater than'* requirement the algorithm properly handles repeating characters. Example: for `"tada"` it will identify a suffix `"da"` and swap the preceding `'a'` with `'d'`, not with the last `'a'`, hence the next permutation found is `"tdaa"`.
As a result the algorithm finds all *distinct* permutations in alphabetic order, unlike algorithms which use the characters' positions only.